# Commas after a loop

Tags: php

I want to add a comma to every username except last one. 
For example: User1, User2, User3
How do I do this? here is my code:

```
$user_online_sql = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT account_id FROM online WHERE account_id != '-1';");
$users = '';
while ($user_online_row = mysql_fetch_array($user_online_sql)) {
$users .= $user->name($user_online_row['account_id']) . ' ';
}
```

I tried the implode function but it just outputted a blank result, here is the code with the implode function:

```
 $user_online_sql = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT account_id FROM online WHERE account_id != '-1';");
$users = '';
while ($user_online_row = mysql_fetch_array($user_online_sql)) {
$users .= implode(', ',$user->name($user_online_row['account_id'])) . ' ';
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right about using `implode`, but you're going about it wrong.

```
$users = []; // or array() in PHP 5.3 and older
while($user_online_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($user_online_sql)) {
    $users[] = $user->name($user_online_row['account_id']);
}
$users = implode(", ",$users);
echo $users;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a comma after every user, and remove the trailing comma.

```
$user_online_sql = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT account_id FROM online WHERE account_id != '-1';");
$users = '';
while ($user_online_row = mysql_fetch_array($user_online_sql)) {
$users .= $user->name($user_online_row['account_id']).',';
}
rtrim ($users, ",");
```